# Java Method returns null although its not null

Tags: java, android, methods, null

I have a class named webservice that cointatins a variable content and a method called getURL that gets an URL as an argument and fetches data and returns it as an string. as following :

```
class WebService {
    String content;
    String getUrl(String url, final Context mContext) {
        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {


            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "Sorry, Something Went Wrong While Connecting To Net :(", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                content = responseString;
                Log.i("RESPONSE STRING", responseString);
                Log.i("COntent STRING", content);

            }
        });
        Log.i("BEFORE RETURN",""+ content);
        return content;


    }
}
```

The Problem is method returns null.
In onSuccess , i check the "content" and the value is exactly like responseString , but in the log before return it turns to null.
could you tell me why this happens?
Thanks.

Comment: because you are doing the assumption that `onSuccess` is called before `return content;`

Comment: You should google what "async" means.

Comment: @Blackbelt so isnt it true?

Comment: if it was, it would have been `sync` not `async`

Comment: @Codebender you need to finalize them just if you declare them in inner classes and methods. it has been declared in class.

Comment: @Blackbelt so in async return calls before other methods? so how can i return response in that way?

Comment: @PouyaHeydari use a synchronous request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `asynchronous Task` will, as the name suggest it, be `asynchronous`. This means it will be done when it's done. Everything else will proceed as usual and don't care about that task - unless you want something back from it.

You can achieve this with various libraries on the web or do it yourself with a callback.

e.g.

```
class WebService {
    public void getUrl(String url, final Context mContext, WebServiceCallback cb) {
    AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
            client.get(url, new TextHttpResponseHandler() {

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                cb.onFailure();
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                cb.onSuccess(responseString);
            }
        });
 }

   public interface WebServiceCallback{
      void onFailure();
      void onSuccess(String url);
  }
}
```

And you call it like that

```
WebService service = new WebService();
service.getUrl("www.test.com", yourContext, new WebServiceCallback(){

    @Override
    public void onFailure(){}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(String url){
        yourAlreadyDeclaredString = url;
        // do smth with it 
    }
});
```

You could also skip this custom callback and pass the `TextHttpResponseHandler`, but this is up to your design.

Comment: Thanks for ur explanation. So in Async methods i shouldnt use return, because usually it calls return statement before onSuccess or onFailure.is that right?

Comment: @PouyaHeydari Yes.